# tensorflow: how come gather_nd is differentiable?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, reinforcement-learning

I'm looking at a tensorflow network implementing reinforcement-learning for the [CartPole](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v0) open-ai env.

The network implements the [likelihood ratio approach](http://adv-ml-2017.wdfiles.com/local--files/course-schedule/rl_class1.pdf) for a policy gradient agent.

The thing is, that the policy loss is defined using the `gather_nd` op!! here, look:

```
    ....
    self.y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(self.W3,self.h2) + self.b3,dim=0)
    self.curr_reward = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)
    self.actions_array = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,2],dtype=tf.int32)
    self.pai_array = tf.gather_nd(self.y,self.actions_array)
    self.L = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(self.pai_array)*self.curr_reward)
```

And then they take the derivative of this loss with respect to all the parameters of the network:

```
    self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.L,tf.trainable_variables())
```

How can this be?? I thought that the whole point in neural networks is always working with differentiable ops, like `cross-entropy` and never do something strange like selecting indexes of `self.y` according to some `self.actions_array` selected by random and clearly not differentiable.

What am I missing here? thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The gradient is one if the parameter is gathered and zero if it is not. One use-case for the gather operator is to act like a sparse one-hot matrix multiplication. The second argument is the dense representation of the sparse matrix and you "multiply" it with the first argument by just selecting the right rows.

Answer (score 1):

It's only differentiable w.r.t. self.y but not the integer/discrete elements of self.actions_array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documentation on this but  according to this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/295 gradient of tf.gather in tensorflow implementation is 1 w.r.t to self.y and 0 w.r.t to index. Therefore, it will not propabagate  gradient through index