# When we do supervised classification with NN, why do we train for cross-entropy and not for classification error?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

The standard supervised classification setup: we have a bunch of samples, each with the correct label out of `N` labels. We build a NN with N outputs, transform those to probabilities with softmax, and the loss is the mean `cross-entropy` between each NN output and the corresponding true label, represented as a `1-hot` vector with `1` in the true label and `0` elsewhere. We then optimize this loss by following its gradient. The classification error is used just to measure our model quality.

HOWEVER, I know that when doing `policy gradient` we can use the [likelihood ratio trick](http://adv-ml-2017.wdfiles.com/local--files/course-schedule/rl_class1.pdf), and we no longer need to use `cross-entropy`! our loss simply `tf.gather` the NN output corresponding to the correct label. E.g. [this solution of OpenAI gym CartPole](https://gist.github.com/shanest/535acf4c62ee2a71da498281c2dfc4f4).

WHY can't we use the same trick when doing supervised learning? I was thinking that the reason we used `cross-entropy` is because it is differentiable, but apparently `tf.gather` is [differentiable as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701722/tensorflow-how-come-gather-nd-is-differentiable).

I mean - IF we measure ourselves on classification error, and we CAN optimize for classification error as it's differentiable, isn't it BETTER to also optimize for classification error instead of this weird `cross-entropy` proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy gradient **is** using cross entropy (or KL divergence, as Ishant pointed out). For supervised learning tf.gather is really just implementational trick, nothing else. For RL on the other hand it is a must because you do not know "what would happen" if you would execute other action. Consequently you end up with high variance estimator of your gradients, something that you would like to avoid for all costs, if possible.

Going back to supervised learning though

```
CE(p||q) = - SUM_i q_i log p_i
```

Lets assume that q_i is one hot encoded, with 1 at k'th position, then

```
CE(p||q) = - q_k log p_k = - log p_k
```

So if you want, you can implement this as tf.gather, it simply does not matter. The cross-entropy is simply more generic because it handles more complex targets. In particular, in TF you have **sparse** cross entropy which does exactly what you describe - exploits one hot encoding, that's it. Mathematically there is no difference, there is small difference computation-wise, and there are functions doing exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks! didn't get the part about avoiding high variance - as you've shown, we're actually using cross-entropy to a one-hot vector in both the supervised and the rl settings. how would you avoid that?

Comment: the thing is in RL case there is no one-hot, there is "true" distribution there, and yet we still only look at the action taken - this is a monte carlo estimate, which has high variance. If we would know all probabilities we could avoid that by computing proper cross entropy, but it is not possible (unless one can "reset' environment to the state before action has been taken, like in tree search methods).

Answer (score 0):

Minimization of cross-entropy loss minimizes the KL divergence between the predicted distribution and the target distribution. Which is indeed the same as maximizing the likelihood of the predicted distribution.

Comment: ok but the target distribution isn't really a distribution! it's very degenerated and has just `1` in one single cell - why can't we just use `gather` of the corresponding cell in our predicted distribution??

Comment: Not really, <you get just `1` in one single cell>, after applying `argmax` on the final_output distribution. For all classification and regression network always model the target distribution.