# How to choose elements (not slice) of a tensor along a dimension in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `3x2x4` tensor:

```
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(24), (3,2,4))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: id=1928, shape=(3, 2, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])>
```

and I'd like to reduce it to `3x2` by indexing along the 3rd dimension. Here is how the indexing vector looks like :

```
y = tf.constant(np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: id=2093, shape=(3, 4), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])>
```

Desired output is:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=2103, shape=(3, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 1,  5],
       [10, 14],
       [16, 20]])>
```

I tried `tf.batch_gather(x, y)` but it gives a different output. Do I need gather_nd or is this solvable with batch_gather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `tf.boolean_mask()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.reshape(tf.range(24), (3,2,4))
y = tf.constant(np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]))

result = tf.boolean_mask(tf.transpose(x,[0,2,1]),y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

[[ 1  5]
 [10 14]
 [16 20]]
```

Comment: @giser-yugang do you know if this operation is differentiable?

Comment: @gkcn You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701722/tensorflow-how-come-gather-nd-is-differentiable. The gradient of `boolean_mask` is calculated in the same way as that of `gather_nd`.